# SQLiteDatabase.openOrCreateDatabase isn't working

Tags: android, sqlite

I've a database in my assets folder. I've tried the below code to load the database.

```
public SQLiteDatabase db;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    db = SQLiteDatabase.openOrCreateDatabase(new File("file:///android_asset/e2b.db"), null);      
    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Error" + db.isOpen(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

I've just tried to open it. Hasn't used it yet. But, when I run my app the window doesn't open with below popup(error)

> Unfortunately, MyDBApp has stopped

The LogCat is below.

> 05-12 13:10:01.673 16004 16004 I   art                                          Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni
>   05-12 13:10:01.877 16004 16004 W   System                                       ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/com.aashakil.e2b2edict-1/lib/arm
>   05-12 13:10:02.227 16004 16004 D   AccessibilityManager                         getInstance() new sInstance = android.view.accessibility.AccessibilityManager@ec2dd0e, context = com.aashakil.e2b2edict.MainActivity@f26932f, userId = 0
>   05-12 13:10:02.288 16004 16004 E   SQLiteLog                                    (14) cannot open file at line 31278 of [2ef4f3a5b1]
>   05-12 13:10:02.288 16004 16004 E   SQLiteLog                                    (14) os_unix.c:31278: (2) open(//file:/android_asset/e2b.db) -
>   05-12 13:10:02.331 16004 16004 E   SQLiteDatabase                               Failed to open database 'file:/android_asset/e2b.db'.
>   05-12 13:10:02.331 16004 16004 E   SQLiteDatabase                               android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCantOpenDatabaseException: unknown error (code 14): Could not open database
>   05-12 13:10:02.331 16004 16004 E   SQLiteDatabase                               at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativeOpen(Native Method)
>   05-12 13:10:02.331 16004 16004 E   SQLiteDatabase                               at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.open(SQLiteConnection.java:207)
>   05-12 13:10:02.331 16004 16004 E   SQLiteDatabase                               at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.open(SQLiteConnection.java:191)
>   05-12 13:10:02.331 16004 16004 E   SQLiteDatabase                               at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.openConnectionLocked(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:463)
>   05-12 13:10:02.331 16004 16004 E   SQLiteDatabase                               at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.open(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:185)
>   05-12 13:10:02.331 16004 16004 E   SQLiteDatabase                               at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.open(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:177)
>   05-12 13:10:02.331 16004 16004 E   SQLiteDatabase                               at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openInner(SQLiteDatabase.java:806)
>   05-12 13:10:02.331 16004 16004 E   SQLiteDatabase                               at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.open(SQLiteDatabase.java:791)
>   05-12 13:10:02.331 16004 16004 E   SQLiteDatabase                               at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:694)
>   05-12 13:10:02.331 16004 16004 E   SQLiteDatabase                               at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openOrCreateDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:709)
>   05-12 13:10:02.331 16004 16004 E   SQLiteDatabase                               at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openOrCreateDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:702)
>   05-12 13:10:02.331 16004 16004 E   SQLiteDatabase                               at com.aashakil.e2b2edict.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:20)
>   05-12 13:10:02.331 16004 16004 E   SQLiteDatabase                               at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6251)
>   05-12 13:10:02.331 16004 16004 E   SQLiteDatabase                               at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1110)
>   05-12 13:10:02.331 16004 16004 E   SQLiteDatabase                               at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2370)
>   05-12 13:10:02.331 16004 16004 E   SQLiteDatabase                               at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2477)
>   05-12 13:10:02.331 16004 16004 E   SQLiteDatabase                               at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
>   05-12 13:10:02.331 16004 16004 E   SQLiteDatabase                               at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1345)
>   05-12 13:10:02.331 16004 16004 E   SQLiteDatabase                               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>   05-12 13:10:02.331 16004 16004 E   SQLiteDatabase                               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
>   05-12 13:10:02.331 16004 16004 E   SQLiteDatabase                               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5452)
>   05-12 13:10:02.331 16004 16004 E   SQLiteDatabase                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>   05-12 13:10:02.331 16004 16004 E   SQLiteDatabase                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:762)
>   05-12 13:10:02.331 16004 16004 E   SQLiteDatabase                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:652)
>   05-12 13:10:02.331 16004 16004 D   AndroidRuntime                               Shutting down VM
>   05-12 13:10:02.333 16004 16004 E   AndroidRuntime                               FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>   05-12 13:10:02.333 16004 16004 E   AndroidRuntime                               Process: com.aashakil.e2b2edict, PID: 16004
>   05-12 13:10:02.333 16004 16004 E   AndroidRuntime                               java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.aashakil.e2b2edict/com.aashakil.e2b2edict.MainActivity}: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCantOpenDatabaseException: unknown error (code 14): Could not open database
>   05-12 13:10:02.333 16004 16004 E   AndroidRuntime                               at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2417)
>   05-12 13:10:02.333 16004 16004 E   AndroidRuntime                               at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2477)
>   05-12 13:10:02.333 16004 16004 E   AndroidRuntime                               at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
>   05-12 13:10:02.333 16004 16004 E   AndroidRuntime                               at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1345)
>   05-12 13:10:02.333 16004 16004 E   AndroidRuntime                               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>   05-12 13:10:02.333 16004 16004 E   AndroidRuntime                               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
>   05-12 13:10:02.333 16004 16004 E   AndroidRuntime                               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5452)
>   05-12 13:10:02.333 16004 16004 E   AndroidRuntime                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>   05-12 13:10:02.333 16004 16004 E   AndroidRuntime                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:762)
>   05-12 13:10:02.333 16004 16004 E   AndroidRuntime                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:652)
>   05-12 13:10:02.333 16004 16004 E   AndroidRuntime                               Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCantOpenDatabaseException: unknown error (code 14): Could not open database
>   05-12 13:10:02.333 16004 16004 E   AndroidRuntime                               at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativeOpen(Native Method)
>   05-12 13:10:02.333 16004 16004 E   AndroidRuntime                               at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.open(SQLiteConnection.java:207)
>   05-12 13:10:02.333 16004 16004 E   AndroidRuntime                               at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.open(SQLiteConnection.java:191)
>   05-12 13:10:02.333 16004 16004 E   AndroidRuntime                               at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.openConnectionLocked(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:463)
>   05-12 13:10:02.333 16004 16004 E   AndroidRuntime                               at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.open(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:185)
>   05-12 13:10:02.333 16004 16004 E   AndroidRuntime                               at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.open(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:177)
>   05-12 13:10:02.333 16004 16004 E   AndroidRuntime                               at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openInner(SQLiteDatabase.java:806)
>   05-12 13:10:02.333 16004 16004 E   AndroidRuntime                               at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.open(SQLiteDatabase.java:791)
>   05-12 13:10:02.333 16004 16004 E   AndroidRuntime                               at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:694)
>   05-12 13:10:02.333 16004 16004 E   AndroidRuntime                               at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openOrCreateDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:709)
>   05-12 13:10:02.333 16004 16004 E   AndroidRuntime                               at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openOrCreateDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:702)
>   05-12 13:10:02.333 16004 16004 E   AndroidRuntime                               at com.aashakil.e2b2edict.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:20)
>   05-12 13:10:02.333 16004 16004 E   AndroidRuntime                               at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6251)
>   05-12 13:10:02.333 16004 16004 E   AndroidRuntime                               at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1110)
>   05-12 13:10:02.333 16004 16004 E   AndroidRuntime                               at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2370)

Comment: check this how to use SQLite https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/sqlite

Comment: AIDE has logcat too, so please provide logs, they're necessary to find a solution

Comment: @valentun How can I see the logcat of AIDE ?

Answer (score 1):

`file:///android_asset` URLs only work with `WebView`, not with file operations in general.

To use a database file from assets you need to copy it to the filesystem. You can use [sqlite-asset-helper](https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-sqlite-asset-helper) to do so.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use different `openOrCreateDatabase` method overload variant:

```
 openOrCreateDatabase("DatabaseName", MODE_PRIVATE, null);
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of calling `openOrCreateDatabase` inside fragment, you need to call it

In Activity :

```
SQLiteDatabase db = openOrCreateDatabase("DATABASE",android.content.Context.MODE_PRIVATE ,null);
```

The correct way in Fragment:

```
SQLiteDatabase db = getActivity().openOrCreateDatabase("DATABASE",android.content.Context.MODE_PRIVATE ,null);**
```